# PowerShell - Duplicate file using a list txt of names

Tags: list, file, powershell, copy, rename

all!

I am trying to solve the following issue using PowerShell.
Basically, I have setup a file with the needed properties. Let's call it "FileA.xlsx".
I have a text file which contains a list of names, i.e:

```
FileB.xlsx
DumpA.xlsx
EditC.xlsx
```

What I am trying is to duplicate "FileA.xlsx" serveral times and use all the names from the text file, so in the end I should end up with 4 files (all of them are copies of "FileA.xlsx":

```
FileA.xlsx
FileB.xlsx
DumpA.xlsx
EditC.xlsx
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a file called files.txt with the following content:

```
bob2.txt
bob3.txt
bob4.txt
```

Then the following will do what you want:

```
$sourceFile = "FileA.xlsx"
gc .\files.txt | % {
    Copy-Item $sourceFile $_
}
```

This will create a copy of the FileA.xlsx with the names bob2.txt, bob3.txt and bob4.txt